# MongoDB add replica sets on running isntances

Tags: mongodb

Does anybody knows of a way to add a replica set to a mongo instance which hasn't been started with -replSet and without restarting it ? In other words is it possible to create a replica set and add already running instances of mongodb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start `mongod` with a `--replSet` parameter (or [`replSet` config file option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#replSet)) in order to use replication.  There are replication background tasks and other server internals that are not enabled in standalone mode.

There is no method (as at MongoDB 2.2.0) to change the role of a running `mongod` instance from standalone to replica set mode (or vice-versa).

> In other words is it possible to create a replica set and add already running instances of mongodb ?

As noted, you would need to restart those instances with the `replSet` parameter.

You can, however, add additional members to a running replica set without downtime.

For more information see the MongoDB manual: [Add Members to a Replica Set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expand-replica-set/).